# Node.js: Is it possible to add global-looking variables to a required module (like __dirname, __filename...)?

Tags: node.js

I can overide wrap method of the module and add global-looking variable 'myVar':

```
var Module = require("module");
(function() {
  Module.wrap = function(script) {
    var wrapper = [
      '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, myVar) { ', '\n});'
    ];
    return wrapper[0] + script + wrapper[1];
  };
```

}(Module.wrap));

but how can I give that variable a value?

Supose I have to overide _compile method, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
process.foo = 'bar';
```

or i'd recommend

```
process.globals = Object();
process.globals.yourVar = 'yourValue';
```

process can be accessed in any nodejs file

Comment: The problem is that myVar can variy in diffrent modules - the same like __filename. so 'globals' is not the decision for me. But thanks any way!

Comment: You could define the custom variable value as regular code in your wrap content, as in: `wrapper = [ '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var myVar = module.id;', ... ];`. Depends on how complex your variable is, obv

Comment: But my module doesn't know about the value I want to give to myVar. I mean I know it only befor requiring module.

Comment: So basically you want something like `require('./my/module', { someVariable: ... })` and give the module code access to that variable? In this case you are better off using `process.env`, `global.someVariable = ...`, or make your module export a function that will be called by the requirer